# Using MySQL and a PHP form to insert data into a relational database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with 3 tables: articles, tags, and articles_tags

The schema for each follows:

**articles:**
id - articletitle - articleorganization - articledate - articleurl

**tags:**
id - tag_contents

**articles_tags:**
id - article_id - tag_id

I also have 2 PHP forms: addnew.php and edit.php

This question specifically concerns addnew.php but it also related to edit.php.

The form in addnew.php does what its name implies and creates new entries into the database. Currently it makes use of some text entry fields and 2 checkboxes. So, for example, I can insert the Title, Author, URL, and Access Date of the article into the **articles** table while also inserting the tags (by checking either or both of the checkboxes) into the **tags** table. What I'm not able to figure out is how do I make these tables intersect with the third table? I've looked around online but I can't seem to find what I need.

For reference the code for addnew.php is below:

```
    <?php
     function renderForm($articletitle, $articleorganization, $articledate, $articleurl, $articletags )
     {
     ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    . . .
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
      . . .
      </div>
        <div class="sidebar1">
        . . .
        </div>
      <div class="content">
            <div id="stylized" class="myform">
          <form id="form" name="form" action="" method="post">
            <h1>Create a new entry in the database</h1>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="6">
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><legend>Article details</legend></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td width="20%" align="right"><span class="field">Article Title:</span></td>
                <td width="80%" align="left"><span class="field">
                  <input name="articletitle" type="text" value="<?php echo $articletitle; ?>" size="50"/>
                </span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><span class="field">Article Author:</span></td>
                <td align="left"><span class="field">
                  <input name="articleorganization" type="text" value="<?php echo $articleorganization; ?>" size="50"/>
                </span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><span class="field">Access Date:</span></td>
                <td align="left"><span class="field">
                  <input name="articledate" type="text" value="MM/DD/YYYY" size="50"/>
                </span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><span class="field">Article URL:</span></td>
                <td align="left"><span class="field">
                <input name="articleurl" type="text" value="<?php echo $articleurl; ?>" size="50"/>
                </span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="right"><span class="field">Article Tags:</span></td>
                <td align="left"><span class="field">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="geology" id="articletags_0" />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="articletags[]" value="astronomy" id="articletags_1" />
                </span></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <footer><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add this Article"></footer>
            </form>
        </div>
      <div class="footer">
       . . .
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php 
     }

     include('settings.php');

     if(count($articletags) > 0)
    {
     $articletags_string = implode(",", $articletags);
    }

     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
     { 

     $articletitle = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articletitle']));
     $articleorganization = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleorganization']));
     $articledate = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articledate']));
     $articleurl = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['articleurl']));
     $articletags = implode(',', $_POST['articletags']);


     if ($articletitle == '' || $articleorganization == '')
     {

     $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';


     renderForm($articletitle, $articleorganization);
     }
      else
     {

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles SET articletitle='$articletitle', articleorganization='$articleorganization', articledate='$articledate', articleurl='$articleurl' ");
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles_tags SET articletags='$articletags' ")


     or die(mysql_error()); 


     header("Location:addsuccess.php"); 
     }
     }
     else

     {
      renderForm('','','','','');
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up a "tag" system for entries in a MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095790/setting-up-a-tag-system-for-entries-in-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use mysql_insert_id to retrieve the last insert id in the query.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles SET articletitle='$articletitle', articleorganization='$articleorganization', articledate='$articledate', articleurl='$articleurl' ");
$article_id = mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tags SET articletags='$articletags' ");
$tag_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_insert_id` to get the id of the last `INSERT` statement.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone comes across this and is using PDO and not mysql the way to do it in PDO is:

```
$article_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Change "$pdo" to whatever your database variable is.